# turning off serial output logs in GCP vm

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Simple question but I can't seem to find the answer to this. When I launch of VM on GCP, I'm getting into the machine via the serial port due to some testing we're doing, but the there what looks like logs from process that continuously log out to the screen (assuming this is stdout when accessing via serial port?). I'm trying to turn this off but can't seem to figure out how to.

here is the version that I'm using:

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let all noisy output to be delivered to the default port `ttyS0` (COM1) and enable alternative login prompt on `ttyS1` (COM2).

To enable alternative serial port temporarily until next reboot:

```
$ sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS1.service
```

To enable alternative serial port permanently:

```
$ sudo systectl enable serial-getty@ttyS1.service
```

Then you might connect to the enabled alternative serial port `ttyS1` from Cloud Shell:

```
CloudShell:$ gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port my-vm --zone=my-zone --port=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way to deactivate the serial ports, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access)

- Either you deactivate it on a specific VM with a metadata value
- Or you can apply an organization policy to avoid the serial port use in your organisation, on folders or on an entire project. (We applied this in my company, for security reasons)